# How to disable password from Jupyter Notebook on remote

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use jupyter notebook from a remote and I know I am able to access it using port tunneling when I ssh:

`ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 me@0.0.0.0`

as when I launch a jupyter notebook on the server and open a browser and go to `http://localhost:8000/` I reach jupyter notebook. But it queues me for a password that I never set up.

If I try to set up a password using:

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

`jupyter notebook password`

and setting a password. This password does not get stored in my jupyter_notebook_config.json file and I get invalid credentials using this password or the hash stored in the json file.

I don't want to be prompted for a password at all! But at the very least I would want to be able to login with the password I specify.

I have worked through all the suggestions I could find so far to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that if you port tunnel with the same port as local (for some reason) and then tell jupyter to use that port, I am able to access the notebook server without a password. The password indicated that I was doing something wrong.

This is what worked:

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 me@0.0.0.0
jupyter notebook --port=8000
```